# how do hashed sharding keys work in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, hash

I wondered what are the internals for hashed sharding keys in mongodb. What is the constant that mongodb chooses to hash my field if it is a timestamp for instance ?
I guess the key will be timestamp % N ; what is N ?
If this is the design, I guess that N cannot change over time. How can I be sure that if I have a LOT of data there will not be too many collisions in 1 shard if N is too small ?
Thanks

Comment: It will md5 the key and use a piece of that md5 to store within the index, can't remember exactly what piece, the source code would say

Answer (score 1):

A hashed key uses the data in the document, and a standard hash function (MD5) to generate a hash value for the document.  For example, suppose your index is on `{name: 'hashed'}` and you have these documents:

```
{name: 'John', height: 73}
{name: 'Zardosht', height: 68}
```

MongoDB will run `'John'` and `'Zardosht'` through the MD5 hash function and get random-looking byte sequences.  Then, it'll use those byte sequences as the actual B-tree key to use in the index.  When you want to do a query for `{name: 'John'}`, it does the MD5 hash again, gets the same byte sequence it would have gotten before, and then actually does an index lookup for that value.

You can play with the mongo shell and actually see what these values will be for yourself:

```
 % mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.2.5/bin/mongo                 
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.5
connecting to: test
> db.runCommand({_hashBSONElement: {name: "John"}})
{
    "key" : {
        "name" : "John"
    },
    "seed" : 0,
    "out" : NumberLong("5553133884637223031"),
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.runCommand({_hashBSONElement: {name: "Zardosht"}})
{
    "key" : {
        "name" : "Zardosht"
    },
    "seed" : 0,
    "out" : NumberLong("8641066842148283865"),
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Note that there isn't an `N` in anything I've described, so you don't have to worry about limits like that.